# CI - getting no error but even database not update

Tags: codeigniter

Please help me, i just messed up. I just checked the code again and again , manipulate code every time but database not updating.

**controller**

```
 function updt_ctrl($id="",$userData=""){

      $userData = array(

         'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
         'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
         'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
         'password' => $this->input->post('password')
         );

      $res=$this->user_model->updt_row($id,$userData);
       if($res){
          $this->load->view('profile_view');
        }
        else{
          echo "something is wrong";
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
    function updt_row($id,$userData){
      //$this->db->set($userData); 
      $this->db->where('id',$id);
      return $this->db->update('user',$userData);
    }
```

Comment: `updt_row($id,$userData)` returns true but table is not changed?

Comment: When updated, you should make redirection to page unless you are doing that over AJAX.

Comment: Yes, i checked by using print_r(), i got updated data in array but table is not updating.

Comment: checking using echo $id?

Comment: `print_r()` as in `print_r($userData)`? And, as @MuhammadUsman asks, you are certain the `$id` is correct?

Comment: How you are calling the function is not mentioned here. Are you passing $id with proper user id value ? Its default value is "" that is why it would not be updating any value in table.

Comment: you are passing `id as NULL`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

**CONTROLLER**

```
function updt_ctrl(){

  $this->load->helper('user_model');

         $userData['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
         $userData['lname'] = $this->input->post('lname');
         $userData['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
         $userData['password'] = $this->input->post('password');


      $this->user_model->updt_row($id,$userData);

    }
```

**MODEL**

```
function updt_row($id,$userData){
      $this->db->where('id', $id);
      $this->db->update('user',$userData);
      //after done update, load this view
      $this->load->view('profile_view');
    }
```

If your embed a correct Form action on your view. this should be working 100%

Answer (score 0):

Replace your contoller  with this

controller

```
function updt_ctrl($id){

      $userData = array(

         'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
         'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
         'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
         'password' => $this->input->post('password')
         );

      $res=$this->user_model->updt_row($id,$userData);
       if($res){
          $this->load->view('profile_view');
        }
        else{
          echo "something is wrong";
        }
    }
```